# How do I choose lines from a text file by date boundaries in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, file, datetime, between

I have this input file:
temp2.txt:

```
82.0    1   77  918     12/04/13        
47.0    1   77  9399    19/06/13        
39.0    1   77  4522    07/07/14        
52.0    1   77  504     13/05/14
```

I want to copy only the lines with the dates between a and b from `temp2.txt` into `output_file.txt`

I wrote this code:

```
import pandas as pd

    a = "01/01/2013"
    b = "31/12/2013"

    df = pd.read_csv('temp2.txt', header=None, sep='\s+')
    df['tmp'] = pd.to_datetime(df[4], errors='coerce')

    df['tmp'] = df['tmp'].between(a, b, inclusive=True)

    df.drop('tmp', axis=1, inplace=True)
    df.to_csv('output_file.txt', header=False, index=False, sep='\t')
```

But it doesn't seem to work for me, I get all of the lines instead of just the 2 that I want.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're not using `df['tmp']` to filter the dataframe... you're creating the column, the immediately removing it, then just writing your original df out... You want something like: `m = pd_to_datetime(df[4], errors='coerce').between(a, b, inclusive=True)` so you've got a boolean mask without creating a new column,  then use it to filter your output rows,  `df[m].to_csv(...)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace `df.drop('tmp', axis=1, inplace=True)` with this.

```
df = df.loc[df['tmp']]
```

So whole code is:

```
import pandas as pd

a = "01/01/2013"
b = "31/12/2013"

df = pd.read_csv('temp2.txt', header=None, sep='\s+')
df['tmp'] = pd.to_datetime(df[4], errors='coerce')

df['tmp'] = df['tmp'].between(a, b, inclusive=True)

df = df.loc[df['tmp']]
df.to_csv('output_file.txt', header=False, index=False, sep='\t')
```